# Categories and sorted systems

Tags: category-theory

Maclane gives a definition (in a survey on categorical algebra) of category in the following way (in my own words), a category is a two-sorted system the sorts being called the objects and the arrows and that satisfies certain properties...

My questions are

What is this system, is a logic, a theory?
Why a category is a two-sorted system?
Then, where are the categories, in another system?

Answer (score 3):

Maclane is saying that category theory can be formalized in a 2-sorted first-order logic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Many-sorted_logic for the basic definition & more. In many-sorted logic you can have multiple discrete domains of individuals; each constant is of a particular sort, and the signature of each argument to a predicate or function includes requirements about which sort(s) of individual can "go there".

Many-sorted first-order logic is really just a notational convenience, it doesn't extend the power of first-order logic[1]. You can eliminate the multiple "sorts" using a predicate for each sort, adding axioms that everything is of some sort and nothing is of more than one sort; the other axioms of the theory have to be modified using these predicates to limit scope to things of the intended sort(s) as needed.

[1]: This paragraph is true when there are finitely many sorts. With infinitely many sorts, however, you can't say "everything is of some sort", as formulas are finite, though with infinitely many sentences you can say that nothing is of any two distinct sorts. See Alex Kruckman's comment for another difference when there are infinitely many sorts.

Comment: One can replace the sorts by predicates when there are only finitely many of them. But there's a problem with this approach when there are infinitely many sorts (see Shelah's $M^\text{eq}$ construction for an example of when this occurs naturally), because it's possible to realize the type of an element not in any of the sort predicates.

Comment: Actually, we really only need to talk about arrows, since an object can be identified with its identity arrow. So, we could work in a 1-sorted theory with language consisting of: unary operations $dom$ and $cod$ and a binary operation $\circ$. I believe Goldblatt's book discusses such an approach.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Point, & thanks. I added a footnote ack'ing your comment. Certainly I was thinking of the finite case. $M^{eq}$ and the study of simple theories does seem to go "on beyond zebra", what with equivalence relations defined by infinite conjunctions of formulas.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes I've seen that done too, with function symbols for *domain* and *codomain* and a partial composition operator or a 3-place predicate. Not in Goldblatt, which I don't know, probably Higgins's book *Categories and Groupoids*, and/or elsewhere.

Comment: "Many-sorted first-order logic is really just a notational convenience, it doesn't extend the power of first-order logic" Yes, and the same argument applies to all theories that can be written in first-order logic by a proper choice of function and predicate symbols together with appropriate axioms.  It is really just a notational convenience.